# How can I test a callback in isolation by manually calling it?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Using scalatest, is it possible to somehow manual trigger a callback to test that my `onComplete` method gets called and doesn't throw an exception?

Since it returns Unit, I just want to make sure it gets called and doesn't error out.

```
class CustomOffsetCallback extends OffsetCommitCallback with Logging {
   override def onComplete(offsets: util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata], exception: Exception): Unit =
     if (exception != null)
       logger.error(s"...")
     else
       logger.debug(s"....")
}
```

Comment: What is this callback thing ?

Comment: @sarveshseri It is kafka related but was hoping I can trigger it manually somehow without this being kafka related even...https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetCommitCallback.html

Comment: Isn't just calling `callback.onComplete(....)` same as triggering the callback ?

Comment: you mean you want to mock/stub `CustomOffsetCallback` and then assert that `onComplete` is called?